# Synching ACFPro repeater fields across languages with wpml-config.xml

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, multilingual, wpml

I have a acfpro repeater field on my wp site that contains a gallery field I am not able to synch across languages.
What would be the way to do that inside the wpml-config.xml?

Figured out how to synch other fields, but not those gallery ones.
Using Polylang as the translation plugin.

Also other question: if I have for example on each page a header image, I like to give the header image field in the different field groups always the same name. How problematic is that? Of course in the wpml-config they just get all synched this way.

Any help would be really appreciated!
Thank you
Stefan

I already tried nesting the fields like this. Works for normal repeater fields but not for gallerys.
"projekte" beeing the repeater and "weitere_fotos" the gallery field.

```
<wpml-config>
  <custom-fields>
    <custom-field action="copy">geschichte_titel</custom-field>
    <custom-field action="copy">projekte_weitere_fotos</custom-field>
  </custom-fields>
</wpml-config>
```